# Hiding the Folders Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a master folder on my disk drive which contains 50 other folders. Now, I want to hide those 50 folders. I can simply right click and select "hide" attribute checkbox but I am looking for a faster way of doing this. Any recommendations?

Windows 8.

Comment: I voted to close this as it is more appropriate for SuperUser. You are not asking a programming question at all.

Comment: As I mentioned I have at least 50-60 folders that needs to be hidden.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For a single file, you can change the `attributes` property, like this:

```
$f=get-item .\your_folder -Force
$f.attributes="Hidden"
```

To hide everything within a folder, you can use `Get-ChildItem`, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path "your_path_here" -Recurse -Force | foreach {$_.attributes = "Hidden"}
```

Comment: If I run this command from inside the parent folder will it add the hidden attributes to all the child folders?

Comment: I just tested it, the first solution it isn't recursive. You can use `Get-ChildItem -path "your_path_here" -Recurse - Force | foreach {$_.attributes = "Hidden"}` to do a recursive change. I updated the answer with this information.

Comment: $f.Attributes+="Hidden"

Answer (score 36):

**The accepted answer presents a potential security issue.**

By overwriting the whole `Attributes` bit field, please be aware that any other attribute previously defined on your file or folder (read-only, **encryption**, ...) will be silently removed.

Use a binary OR to prevent this behavior:

```
Get-Item .\your_folder -Force | foreach { $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bor "Hidden" }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be Get-ChildItem ?

Answer (score 5):

Both of the other answers have issues. Here is an answer that fixes them based on the comments, both in short notation and in longer notation:

```
gci -r $folder | % { $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bor "Hidden" }
# alternatively
Get-ChildItem -Recurse $folder | ForEach-Object { $_.Attributes = $_.Attributes -bor "Hidden" }
```

Explanations:

1. [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp) (alias `gci` or `ls`) lists files in a folder. The `-Recurse` (alias `-r`) also lists files in subfolders, subfolders of subfolders, etc. The `-Force` parameter in the other answers is not really needed: its purpose is to list files that are already hidden, which is pointless if what you want to do is hide it afterwards.
   However, if you want to *unhide* your files, then you need to add the `-Force` parameter, so that you get a command like (in short notation)

   ```
   gci -r -fo $folder | % { $_.attributes -bor "Hidden" -bxor  "Hidden" }
   ```
2. [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1) (alias `%` or `foreach`) iterates over the input objects. Its parameter is a script block `{ ... }` in which the current object is the special variable `$_`.
3. In that script block, `$_` is a [`System.IO.FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo?view=net-5.0). Its [`Attribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes?view=net-5.0#System_IO_FileSystemInfo_Attributes) parameter contains the attributes of the file. This is a [`FileAttribute` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileattributes?view=net-5.0). One of the possible attributes is "Hidden" (the second bit in the enum, but it's not really important).
4. The [`-bor` (bitwise or) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators) adds the "Hidden" bit to the enum. Note that the `=` operator would overwrite all the other attributes of that file, which could be problematic.

Comment: @xjcl You're right, it doesn't. If the file is already hidden, then there is an issue. I don't think that `gci` without `-force` can return hidden files, but one never knows. I've fixed my answer to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Simple Command Hide Folder

```
attrib +h TestFolder
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that using `$f.Attributes += 'Hidden'` or `$f.Attributes -= 'Hidden'` will actually *toggle* the hidden flag i.e. using `$f.Attributes += 'Hidden'` on a file that is already hidden will unhide it, and vice versa.

The example to hide an item mentioned in earlier posts is idempotent i.e.:

```
$f.Attributes = $f.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden
```

To unhide idempotently, you can use:

```
$f.Attributes = $f.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden
```

Comment: Why not just `$f.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden`?

Comment: @xjcl Good point; edited to include your version.